# why java.util.Date and Calendar are not completely deprecated in Java8?

Tags: java-8, deprecated

When one looks at the javadoc of the `java.util.Date` class, most of the methods are already deprecated for a extended period of time. Now in java8, brand new package `java.time` was introduced with mature replacements for `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes
Why not step one step further and deprecate old classes completely? Are there any plans to deprecate them in Java9 or 10?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/class-use/Date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reason could be the backwards compatibility for software developed with older versions. This is just the indication that in future versions, the complete class may become deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9 `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are also not deprecated. There are quite a bit of usages of [Calendar](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@8u40-b25@java%24util@Calendar&k=u) and [Date](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24root@jdk%24openjdk@8u40-b25@java%24util@Date&k=u) in open source software. I think that creators of Java do not want to break backward compatibility now.